# extracting part of filename and add them as value in column

Tags: r

I have imported multiple excel files at once (more then 20) in R and I want to give values to columns in the dataframe based on the file name.

Let us say that the filename are the following: "A1_412", "A1_413" , "A1_415" , "A2_412", "A2_413", "A2_415" , "A23_413" "A4_5", "A6_413_TS"... etc

I want to create two column where the value in column_1 will show A1, A2, A23 if these row are from the file A1_412, A1_413 or A1_415

the value in column_2 will show 412 or 413 or 415 based on the name of the file

I have already imported all the files

```
#import all the excel files
file.list <- list.files(path = "xxxxxxxxxx",    
                       pattern = "*.xlsx",
                       full.names = TRUE) 

alldata<-file.list %>%
  map_dfr(~read_excel(.x)%>%
  mutate_all(as.character))
```

this is an example of the end result that im searching for:

```
G     B column_1 column_2
a  Lion       A1      415
b   Cat       A1      412
c Horse      A23      413
d   dog       A2      415
e Mouse      A23      413
f Snake       A2      412
g zebra       A6      413
h bird
```

bird is coming from the file A4_5, I want the column_1 to be empty instead of showing A4 and column_2 to be empty instead of showing 5
Zebra is coming from file A6_413_TS so here I want column_1 to show A6 and column_2 to only show 413
zebra is coming

I need a solution that can be generalized to a large number of variables.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Do you mean column_1 will show "A1", "A2", "A23" if the rows are from the file "A1_412", "A2_413", or "A23_415"?.. That is column1 will have the prefix (i.e. before the underscore) and column 2 will hold the suffix (i.e. after the underscore)?

Comment: You will have to ask a different question. Give the starting dataset and the expected output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
file.list %>%
  set_names(.) %>%
  map_df(~mutate_all(read_excel(.x), as.character), .id = 'grp') %>%
  mutate(grp = str_remove(basename(grp), ".xlsx")) %>%
  separate(grp, c('col1', 'col2'), sep = '_', extra = 'merge')
```

Comment: @onyambu Thanks but I get the following error  Can't combine  <character> and  <double>.

Comment: @ev123R try it now

Comment: @Adam thats an error mostly for `bind_rows`. try `1:10 %>%map_dfr(~data.frame(.x*2), .id = 'grp')` for example

Comment: @Adam you are right. Will fix that asap

Comment: It actually worked fine, but I'm having issue with two file names. One looks like A4_5 and the other looks like A6_413_TS. I forgot to add these to my original post. I just updated the original post

Comment: @ev123R the post has not been editted. Also consider upvoting even if it solves half of your problem

Comment: the post has been updated with:                                                                
bird is coming from the file A4_5, I want the column_1 to be empty instead of showing A4 and column_2 to be empty instead of showing 5 Zebra is coming from file A6_413_TS so here I want column_1 to show A6 and column_2 to only show 413 zebra is coming

Comment: @ev123R The post (ORIGINAL QUESTION) was last editted 31 minutes ago. You just have the end results but you do not have the starting dataframe. Notice that this question was talking about separating the names of the files into two. The answers given tackle that. If you are talking about the dataset rather than the files name, that should be a question asked separately Consider accepting one of the solutions provided and then ask a follow up question

Comment: it's not about the dataset, it is still the files names. If a file name looks like A6_413_TS or A4 the end result is not what I expected.

Comment: @ev123R provide the dataset with the mentioned problem. You only provide the output. But you have not provided the problem. You need to ask a question providing a dataset and then state the output you want. This has nothing to do with the names. It has everything to do with data manipulation. Once you get the answer you will be able to incorporate it into your task

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this. Basically, I use `lapply()` to loop over the filenames, each time using `basename()` to get the base file name, and then use `str_remove()` to remove the extension, and `strsplit` to split on the `_` between the prefix and the suffix

```
bind_rows(
  lapply(file.list, function(f) {
    bn = basename(f)
    colvals = strsplit(str_remove(bn, ".xlsx"), "_")[[1]]
    read_excel(f) %>% mutate_all(as.character()) %>% mutate(col1 = colvals[1], col2=colvals[2])
  })
)
```

Comment: Thanks @langtang but I get the following error  Can't combine  <character> and  <double>.